# Matlab Guide Button Glitch-

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am trying to make it such that I display an average of four numbers and a function which takes the average as its input. However, if a pushbutton is pressed I want the function to display "0". Below is my attempt, but the problem is that I am attempting to store the state of the button in `handles.button_state` but my value does not seem to store properly, as the global variable stays to my initialized value of `false`, and the problem is that my if statement to either display the function or the value "0" always displays the value of the function if I press my "calculate" button more than once, instead of staying "0" if the button is pressed.

```
function varargout = Real2(varargin)

% REAL2 MATLAB code for Real2.fig

%      REAL2, by itself, creates a new REAL2 or raises the existing

%      singleton*.

%

%      H = REAL2 returns the handle to a new REAL2 or the handle to

%      the existing singleton*.

%

%      REAL2('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local

%      function named CALLBACK in REAL2.M with the given input arguments.

%

%      REAL2('Property','Value',...) creates a new REAL2 or raises the

%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are

%      applied to the GUI before Real2_OpeningFcn gets called.  An

%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application

%      stop.  All inputs are passed to Real2_OpeningFcn via varargin.

%

%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one

%      instance to run (singleton)".

%

% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES




% Edit the above text to modify the response to help Real2




% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 07-Feb-2017 18:09:44




% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT

gui_Singleton = 1;

gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...

                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...

                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @Real2_OpeningFcn, ...

                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @Real2_OutputFcn, ...

                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...

                   'gui_Callback',   []);

if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})

    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});

end




if nargout

    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

else

    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

end

% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT







% --- Executes just before Real2 is made visible.

function Real2_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.

% hObject    handle to figure

% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB

% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% varargin   command line arguments to Real2 (see VARARGIN)




% Choose default command line output for Real2

handles.output = hObject;




% Update handles structure

guidata(hObject, handles);

initialize_gui(hObject, handles, false);

% UIWAIT makes Real2 wait for user response (see UIRESUME)

% uiwait(handles.figure1);







% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.

function varargout = Real2_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 

% Get default command line output from handles structure

varargout{1} = handles.output;










%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------%













function Number1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

Number1 = str2double(get(hObject, 'String'));




handles.metricdata.Number1 = Number1;

guidata(hObject,handles)




% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.

function Number1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))

    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');

end










%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------%







function Number2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

Number2 = str2double(get(hObject, 'String'));

handles.metricdata.Number2 = Number2;

guidata(hObject,handles)




% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.

function Number2_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))

    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');

end










%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------%













function Number3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

Number3 = str2double(get(hObject, 'String'));

handles.metricdata.Number3 = Number3;

guidata(hObject,handles)




% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.

function Number3_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))

    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');

end



















function Number4_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

Number4 = str2double(get(hObject, 'String'));

handles.metricdata.Number4 = Number4;

guidata(hObject,handles)

% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.

function Number4_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)

if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))

    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');

end













%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

% --------------------------------------------------------------------

% --- Executes on button press in Togz.

function Togz_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% hObject    handle to Togz (see GCBO)

% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB

% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)




% Hint: get(hObject,'Value') returns toggle state of Togz

button_state = get(hObject,'Value');

handles.button_state = button_state;

set(handles.funcz, 'String', 0);

%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------%




% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.

function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)

% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB

% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)




average = (handles.metricdata.Number1+handles.metricdata.Number2+handles.metricdata.Number3+handles.metricdata.Number4)/4;

funcz= 2*average^2-3*average+2;

set(handles.average, 'String', average);




if handles.button_state==true

    set(handles.funcz, 'String', 0);

else

    set(handles.funcz, 'String', funcz);

end










function initialize_gui(fig_handle, handles, isreset)

% If the metricdata field is present and the reset flag is false, it means

% we are we are just re-initializing a GUI by calling it from the cmd line

% while it is up. So, bail out as we dont want to reset the data.

if isfield(handles, 'metricdata') && ~isreset

    return;

end




handles.metricdata.Number1 = 0;

handles.metricdata.Number2 = 0;

handles.metricdata.Number3 = 0;

handles.metricdata.Number4 = 0;

handles.button_state = false;




set(handles.Number1, 'String', handles.metricdata.Number1);

set(handles.Number2, 'String', handles.metricdata.Number2);

set(handles.Number3, 'String', handles.metricdata.Number3);

set(handles.Number4, 'String', handles.metricdata.Number4);

set(handles.funcz, 'String', 1);

set(handles.average, 'String', 0);










% Update handles structure

guidata(handles.figure1, handles);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`handles` is not a global variable but rather it is stored within the figure itself and automatically passed to all callbacks as the third input. If you want to make a modification to the `handles` structure, you have to *save* the changes to the `handles` structure by re-assigning it to the figure using `guidata`.

```
% Change the value
handles.button_state = button_state;

% "Save" these changes
guidata(hObject, handles)
```